# com.fortify.sca.analyzer.a: There is not enough memory available to complete analysis

Tags: fortify

Getting below error with Fortify Audit Workbench aplication :

[error]: Unexpected exception while parsing *.js
com.fortify.sca.analyzer.a: There is not enough memory available to complete analysis.  For details on making more memory available, please consult the user manual.

Any solution please !!!

Answer (score 9):

Your translation step is running out of memory.  You can pass the -Xmx flag to give the jvm more memory to complete the task.  For example, to give 2G you could pass the `-Xmx2G` flag to the translation step.  You might also want to ensure you're running in 64bit mode (if your OS and HW support it) by passing the -64 flag.

Ultimately, this (and more) is described in detail in the `HP_Fortify_SCA_User_Guide_3.xx.pdf` that ships with your product.

Comment: This doesn't actually necessarily occur from just an issue to do with the heap space, it can also be occurred by other memory issues such as permgen space or stack space issues. To find detailed findings, run with -debug -logfile scan.log and then in the logs look for lines (and the one after) with SEVERE in them.

Answer (score 2):

If the file contains Minified Javascript then Fortify SCA may never be able to parse it. Use the un-minified version of the file for the scan.